# nginx ssl config for cert.pem and chain.pem

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

The [certbot docs](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#where-are-my-certificates) say this for `cert.pem` and `chain.pem`:

> If you provide one of these files to your web server, you must provide both of them, or some browsers will show “This Connection is Untrusted” errors for your site, some of the time.

This is the typical nginx config:

```
ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

???                     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem;
```

Where do I set `cert.pem`?

Comment: `fullchain.pem` includes the content of `cert.pem`. You only need the first two lines with Nginx. The separate cert file is only required for other web servers.

Comment: @RichardSmith That's what I thought, but that warning is pretty scary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fullchain.pem` includes the content of `cert.pem`. You only need the first two lines with Nginx. The separate cert file is only required for other web servers.